# How to set Exim envelope domain to From domain

Tags: exim, dmarc

I've set up DKIM on Exim with the domain set like:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sender_address_domain}
```

However, the domain is always set to the same domain (my primary domain), which causes DMARC validation to fail, because of alignment, when sending emails for other domains (I host several websites).

From reading the documentation, I think the sender_address_domain is the envelope address and not the From field. How can I change the envelope address so that it matches the From field of a given email (I assume this will also allow SPF alignment to be correct)?

Also, for security, is it possible to have a whitelist of allowable domains, so Exim refuses to send emails that have another domain in the From field?

Comment: It looks like you are using the Debian exim config, as you use `DKIM_DOMAIN` in capitals? As far as I know this is initialized at startup so using a per-message variable to set it will not work. As I read it you need to specify the list of possible domains here, the correct one should be selected.

Comment: @wurtel Correct, I'm using Debian's. But, I'm not sure that makes any difference, they just do `dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN`. So, how might I configure the variable per-message as you suggest?

Comment: Same thing, `dkim_domain` is set at startup as far as I know. Note that it's a list, perhaps include all domains this exim might send email for.

Comment: @wurtel Tried setting `DKIM_DOMAIN = foo.com : bar.com`, but this just results in DKIM not getting set at all. Even if that worked, I'm still unsure how I would change the sender domain for the SPF as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the rewrite rule:

```
*       "${address:$header_from:}" F
```

Where `${address:$header_from:}` extracts the address from the `From` header and [`F` means to rewrite the Envelope-from field](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html#SSECID154).

In debian this can be added by creating a file such as `/etc/exim4/conf.d/rewrite/10_from_rewrite`. This rule rewrites the sender field to match the From header, allowing DMARC alignment to work correctly.

---

For the whitelist, we can add a system filter. First create the filter file (e.g. `/etc/exim4/exim.filter`):

```
# Exim filter

if not foranyaddress "domain1.com, domain2.com" ($thisaddress is "${domain:$header_from:}")
then fail "${domain:$header_from:} not permitted to send email" endif
```

Then in the main part of the config somewhere add `system_filter = /etc/exim4/exim.filter`.

I've not figured out any way to use the domainlist/local_domains within this filter.

Answer (score 4):

Add the rewrite rule to the Exim4 configuration:

```
*@+local_domains "${local_part}@${domain}" F
```

The rule rewrites the Envelope-from header to match the From header, allowing DMARC alignment to work correctly.
Recommendation is to append it to the end of the section to avoid conflicts with current rules.

You can find this configuration in the file `/etc/exim4/conf.d/rewrite/10_from_rewrite` or in the section called `rewrite/31_exim4-config_rewriting` of the file `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` (for Debian). It depends on the type of your configuration – called [single monolithic or split Exim4 config file](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Configuration) with possible need to run the command `update-exim4.conf`.

Restart Exim after reconfiguration using `systemctl restart Exim4`.

---

The rule explanation:

- `*` of the `*@+local_domains` = for all "local_parts" e.g. users.
- `+local_domains` = for all domains served by Exim4 server (defined in `dc_other_hostnames` and `dc_readhost` variables) and not by other domains (redirection attempts etc.).
- `${local_part}@${domain}` composes RFC2822 compliant e-mail address from From field. Variables are described in [exim4 documentation – string expansions](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html). You can use just "$header_from:", but addresses in a form as "John Doe <john.doe@example.net>" will fail and get recorded to paniclog because of the "John Doe" part.
- `F` = target field of rewrite operation is the Envelope-from. see [exim4 documentation – address rewriting](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html#SECID154).

Comment: This has stopped working. Not sure if something has changed, but `$local_part` and `$domain` seem to refer to the address that is currently being rewritten. So, this rewrite rule just outputs the same domain. The `+local_domains` has also never worked at restricting the domains that are rewritten. I've reverted to my previous answer which still seems to work.

Comment: I added `${address:}` to my answer which should resolve the previous concern with using the header. I think the reason that `+local_domains` doesn't work is because it is matching against the envelope address before rewriting, and will therefore always be the same. We want to match against the From header or the result of the transformation instead.